# How to get a .txt file in the same package as my .java file?

Tags: java, file, io, resources, package

I need to get the path of the .txt file in my package on startup, but I don't find a way to do so. Google does not help me with solutions that work.

It's `Test/src/test/main.java` and `Test/src/test/file.txt` in Eclipse.

Everything is in the main method because the `do something` is so short that an extra function or class is not worth it.

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(???) {
    lines.forEach(line -> {
        // "do something with the line"
    }
}
```

Comment: please keep in mind that Eclipse executes projects form their root-directories, not their `src` folders. You may add a `src/` in front of the path: `Paths.get("src/yourPackage/yourFile.txt)`

Comment: the root directory at runtime is Test.

Comment: Wow it works, tried 6 different solution I found via Google on stackoverflow, nothing worked. Thank you so much :).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read the file in, use a file reader and pass the path of your file in the form of a string.

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file");
```